# Move cursor at the begining/end of the 'active' line in C

Tags: vim

I've already mapped `<Home>` to `^` in order to move the cursor to the first non empty char of the line (skipping the indentation).

I would like to do the same for `<End>` but I also would like to skip the comment which allow me to move around the *active* part of the code easily:

```
// A line of C:
      if (foo == bar) {        // Comment
^     ^               ^                 ^
|    '^' or <Home>     <End>           '$' or <C-End>   
|
'0' or <C-Home>
```

Here the trick for `<Home>`

```
noremap <Home> ^
inoremap <silent> <Home> <C-c>^i
inoremap <C-Home>   <C-c>0i
nnoremap <C-Home>   0

" Use `$` to move physically at the end of the line 
" (Virtualedit must be enabled)
nmap <C-End>    $
```

Now I am looking for a solution for `<End>`.

Any idea?

P.S. Feel free to change the title of my question I don't know how to say it in a better way...

Comment: You can also move the cursor to the opening brace by typing `f{`. While it is not necessarily quicker, it certainly requires less hand movement, which is one of Vim's selling points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal and insert mode movements, you can just follow up the `$` jump to the end with an optional search for the beginning of the comment. The use of `search()` prevents beeping and error messages in case of no match, and doesn't clobber your current search:

```
nnoremap <silent> <End> $:call search('\S\s*/[/*]', 'bcW')<CR>
```